# custom controls for html5 animation (scrubber play stop)

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to work out how to get controls the same as for a video for an html5 animation, ie controlling a youtube video but instead of a .mp4 video being controlled by the player, rather a html5 canvas animation.
this being the basic idea:
[image: example]
!

Basically just want to be pushed in the right direction for what i could search because so far whenever i try the only thing i can find are html5 video players that control video (.mp4/.mov/etc) and not animations.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/). Here is a [demo showcasing exactly, what you want](http://cdpn.io/AwCKp).